# Sorting an array using the numeric value of strings it contains

Tags: ruby

I have a file called `highscore.txt` which will be read into the program and put into an array. The problem is that I can not sort the array because the points in the .txt file are read as strings, not as integers... how can I fix this?

`highscore.txt`:

[image: Nico,11\nLuis,7...]

Code:

```
@Bestenliste.each do |stat|
  @sorted = @sorted + [stat.to_s.split(",")]
end
@sorted = @sorted.sort {|a,b| a[1] <=> b[1]}
@sorted.each do |stat2|
  puts stat2[0].to_s + " | " + stat2[1].to_s
end
```

With `stat.to_s.split` I split one line (`Nico,10`) into two objects but the 10 will be a string so I can't sort the array anymore.

And yes I'm doing this in quite a complicated way since I'm new to Ruby. ^^

Comment: Mind showing the code you tried ?

Comment: You can get your above code working by just modifying this line `@sorted.sort {|a,b| a[1] <=> b[1]}` to `@sorted.sort {|a,b| a[1].to_i <=> b[1].to_i}`. While you can follow @avlazarov's answer as he is correct on that. But if you just want your exiting code to work then you can do the above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is to convert the convert the strings to integers before comparing them. In the code you posted, this would be as simple as appending a `.to_i` to the values you are comparing in the line the sorts the array:

```
@sorted = @sorted.sort {|a,b| a[1].to_i <=> b[1].to_i}
```

As you seem to have realized though, Ruby is a pretty powerful language. There are much more readable, compact ways of doing what you did. For example, a program which does what you described could easily be implemented in one or two lines:

```
highscores = File.readlines('highscore.txt').map{|line| line.split(',') }
puts highscores.sort_by{|_, score| score.to_i}.map{|pair| pair.join(" | ")}
```

Answer (score 1):

`array.sort_by(&:to_i)` - will sort the array by calling `#to_i` for every string, and return an array of the scores still in strings
`array.map(&:to_i).sort` - same but will return an array of ints

Edit: Or use `to_f` instead of `to_i` if the scores are floats

Comment: Won't that turn the whole array into integer? I just want the numbers to be converted

Comment: Then just `array.map(&to_f)`, where the `array` holds your string values of the score

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the strings to a different type.  Possibly Integer or Float..

For this file:

```
75.89
87.23
81.98
99.40
45.81
```

look at this snippet from irb:

```
1.9.3-p194 :016 > File.readlines('test.txt').each do |line|
1.9.3-p194 :017 >   puts "#{line} - #{line.class}"
1.9.3-p194 :018?>   puts "#{line.to_i} - #{line.to_i.class}"
1.9.3-p194 :019?>   puts "#{line.to_f} - #{line.to_f.class}"
1.9.3-p194 :020?>   end
75.89 - String
75 - Fixnum
75.89 - Float
87.23 - String
87 - Fixnum
87.23 - Float
81.98 - String
81 - Fixnum
81.98 - Float
99.40 - String
99 - Fixnum
99.4 - Float
45.81 - String
45 - Fixnum
45.81 - Float
```